# Building LMMS: "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!"

Tags: compiling, software-sources, install-from-source, make

I tried to build Linux MultiMedia studio from the source of the SourceForge `git://` repository under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32b:

```
git clone git://lmms.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/lmms/lmms
cd lmms
git checkout
```

First I tried to install all the required libraries and then I `cmake`d. -
That's what happened on `cmake` (`errors occurred!`):

```
[DIR]lmms/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
PROCESSOR: i686
Machine: i686-linux-gnu
-- Target host is 32 bit
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDINT_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDINT_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDBOOL_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDBOOL_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDLIB_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDLIB_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SEMAPHORE_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SEMAPHORE_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_UNISTD_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_UNISTD_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_IPC_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_IPC_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_SHM_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_SHM_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_TIME_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_TIME_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDARG_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STDARG_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SIGNAL_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SIGNAL_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SCHED_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SCHED_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_SOUNDCARD_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_SOUNDCARD_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SOUNDCARD_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SOUNDCARD_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_FCNTL_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_FCNTL_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_CTYPE_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_CTYPE_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STRING_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_STRING_H - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_PROCESS_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_PROCESS_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_LOCALE_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_LOCALE_H - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found suitable version "4.8.1", required is "4.6.0;COMPONENTS;QtCore;QtGui;QtXml;QtNetwork")
-- Found Qt translations in /usr/share/qt4/translations
-- checking for module 'sndfile>=1.0.11'
--   found sndfile, version 1.0.25
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
-- Found libzip: /usr/lib/libzip.so
-- Found libflac++: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC++.so
-- Found STK: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstk.so
-- checking for module 'portaudio-2.0'
--   found portaudio-2.0, version 19
-- Found Portaudio: portaudio;asound;m;pthread
-- checking for module 'libpulse'
--   found libpulse, version 1.1
-- Found PulseAudio Simple: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so
-- Looking for vorbis_bitrate_addblock in vorbis
-- Looking for vorbis_bitrate_addblock in vorbis - found
-- Found OggVorbis: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so
-- Looking for snd_seq_create_simple_port in asound
-- Looking for snd_seq_create_simple_port in asound - found
-- Found ALSA: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_MACHINE_SOUNDCARD_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_MACHINE_SOUNDCARD_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_LINUX_AWE_VOICE_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_LINUX_AWE_VOICE_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_AWE_VOICE_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_AWE_VOICE_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE__USR_SRC_SYS_I386_ISA_SOUND_AWE_VOICE_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE__USR_SRC_SYS_I386_ISA_SOUND_AWE_VOICE_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE__USR_SRC_SYS_GNU_I386_ISA_SOUND_AWE_VOICE_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE__USR_SRC_SYS_GNU_I386_ISA_SOUND_AWE_VOICE_H - not found.
-- Looking for C++ include sys/asoundlib.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/asoundlib.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include alsa/asoundlib.h
-- Looking for C++ include alsa/asoundlib.h - found
-- Looking for snd_pcm_resume in asound
-- Looking for snd_pcm_resume in asound - found
-- checking for module 'jack>=0.77'
--   found jack, version 0.121.2
-- checking for module 'fftw3f>=3.0.0'
--   package 'fftw3f>=3.0.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:309 (PKG_CHECK_MODULES)


-- checking for module 'fluidsynth>=1.0.7'
--   found fluidsynth, version 1.1.5
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_LV2CORE
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_LV2CORE - found
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SLV2_SCALEPOINTS_H
-- Looking for include files LMMS_HAVE_SLV2_SCALEPOINTS_H - not found.
-- Looking for slv2_world_new in slv2
-- Looking for slv2_world_new in slv2 - found
-- Looking for librdf_new_world in rdf
-- Looking for librdf_new_world in rdf - found
-- Looking for wine_init in wine
-- Looking for wine_init in wine - found
-- Looking for C++ include windows.h
-- Looking for C++ include windows.h - found
-- checking for module 'samplerate>=0.1.7'
--   package 'samplerate>=0.1.7' not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_LRINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_LRINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_LRINTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_LRINTF - Success
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_POSITIVE
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_POSITIVE - Failed
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_NEGATIVE
-- Performing Test CPU_CLIPS_NEGATIVE - Success
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so 

Installation Summary
--------------------
* Install Directory           : /usr/local
* Use system's libsamplerate  : 

Supported audio interfaces
--------------------------
* ALSA                        : OK
* JACK                        : OK
* OSS                         : OK
* PortAudio                   : OK
* PulseAudio                  : OK
* SDL                         : OK

Supported MIDI interfaces
-------------------------
* ALSA                        : OK
* OSS                         : OK
* WinMM                       : <not supported on this platform>

Supported file formats for project export
-----------------------------------------
* WAVE                        : OK
* OGG/VORBIS                  : OK
* FLAC                        : OK

Optional plugins
----------------
* SoundFont2 player           : OK
* Stk Mallets                 : OK
* VST-instrument hoster       : OK
* VST-effect hoster           : OK
* LV2 hoster                  : OK
* CALF LADSPA plugins         : OK
* CAPS LADSPA plugins         : OK
* CMT LADSPA plugins          : OK
* TAP LADSPA plugins          : OK
* SWH LADSPA plugins          : OK
* FL .zip import              : OK


-----------------------------------------------------------------
IMPORTANT:
after installing missing packages, remove CMakeCache.txt before
running cmake again!
-----------------------------------------------------------------



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Here are some parts the contents of my `lmms/build/CMakeCache.txt` file:

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: /home/jk/Downloads/lmms-git/lmms/build
# It was generated by CMake: /usr/bin/cmake
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUI's for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Path to a file.
ALSA_INCLUDES:PATH=/usr/include

//Path to a library.
ASOUND_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ar

//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//CXX compiler.
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds (/MD /Ob1 /Oi
// /Ot /Oy /Gs will produce slightly less optimized but smaller
// files).
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g

//C compiler.
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds (/MD /Ob1 /Oi
// /Ot /Oy /Gs will produce slightly less optimized but smaller
// files).
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g

//Flags used by the linker.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=' '

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Enable/Disable output of compile commands during generation.
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=OFF

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ld

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/make

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=' '

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

==[...]==
```

That's a list of the contents of my `lmms/build` folder:

```
[DIR]lmms/build$ dir
CMakeCache.txt     CPackSourceConfig.cmake  lmmsconfig.h   plugins
CMakeFiles     data             lmms.rc
CPackConfig.cmake  include          lmmsversion.h
```

**My Question:** It just tells me that that "errors" occurred, but I can't see any error message. It seems like everything went fine. - So: Any idea what the problem could be? - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*-- checking for module 'fftw3f>=3.0.0'
--   package 'fftw3f>=3.0.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found*

You might try:

```
sudo apt-get install libfftw3-3 libfftw3-dev libsamplerate0 libsamplerate0-dev
```

Then try cmake again and install more packages as needed. Often, when there are errors in compiling, the -dev package is also needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. - At the moment I don't have access to my Ubuntu machine, but I'm going to try that out right in the morning.

Comment: I will look forward to your report. In my experience, you may get further along with cmake and it may find another error. You'll need to figure out, perhaps with guesswork, what package it wants and install it along with the -dev package. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, `cmake`'s working now, after running `sudo apt-get install libfftw3-3[...]`. - But when I've wanted to `make` it, there was another error: `/usr/include/librdf.h:31:21: [...] raptor2.h: No such file or directory` - Any idea concerning that? Thanks.

Comment: I think it means you probably have librdf0 installed but it also wants librdf0-dev. I suggest you try to install both, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. - But I've already installed `librdf0`. Another idea what could help?

Comment: You might try raptor2-utils. When I just now installed librdf0-DEV, it installed raptor2-utils as a dependency and raptor2.h appeared on my system: /usr/include/raptor2/raptor2.h.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I've already installed `librdf0-dev` and `raptor2-utils` too. There's also a file called `/usr/include/raptor2/raptor2.h` on my system. But the error message is still there. - So: Any idea what else could help in this case?

Comment: Please try: sudo apt-get build-dep lmms; rm CMakeCache.txt; cmake. Any errors?

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep lmms; rm CMakeCache.txt; cmake` works fine. But when running `make -j2`, there's still the same fatal error: **`In file included from /usr/include/slv2/world.h:26:0,¶ from [DIR]lmms/include/lv2_manager.h:33,¶ from [DIR]lmms/include/lv2_2_lmms.h:30,¶ from [DIR]lmms/src/core/lv2_2_lmms.cpp:27:¶ /usr/include/librdf.h:31:21: Fatal error: raptor2.h: No such file or directory`** - Do you know about anything else I could try out? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you tried and rejected the version of lmms in the Ubuntu repositories. I'd email the author: <tobydox/at/users/dot/sourceforge/dot/net>